# Get data from POST request REST API Django

Tags: django, django-views

I am struggling with this from last 2 days

If I am using GET request everything is fine but if I am using POST request I am getting None value for Keys

I am using POSTMAN to fire the POST request, I have added comment where I am getting None in case of POST request. Can any one give me a fix for this.

I am using Django1.9

below is the code

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http.response import Http404, HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate,login,logout
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from ironman.models import *
import json
from django.template import RequestContext
from dashboard.models import PromoCluster,Beacon
from datetime import datetime
from django.contrib.gis.measure import D
from django.contrib.gis.geos import *
from django.contrib.gis.geos.factory import fromstr
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.db import IntegrityError
from django.contrib.auth import logout

# Create your views here

@csrf_exempt
def signup(request):
    if request.method != 'POST':
        raise Http404
    email = request.POST.get('email')
    print " email is %s," % email # this is returning None.
    password = request.POST.get('password')
    print " password is %s," % password  # This is also returning None 
    name = request.POST.get('name')
    os = request.POST.get('os')
    device_id = request.POST.get('device_id')
    version = request.POST.get('version')
    device = request.POST.get('device')
    emailSecond = email;
    print " email is " , emailSecond
    try:
        user = User.objects.create_user(username=emailSecond,email=email,password=password)
        app_user_detail = AppUserDetail.objects.get(user=user)
        app_user_detail.device_id = device_id
        app_user_detail.os = os
        app_user_detail.version = version
        app_user_detail.device = device
        app_user_detail.save()
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps({"status": 200}), content_type='application/json')
    except IntegrityError:
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps({"status":201,"message":"user already exists , please try different user name "}), content_type='application/json')
```

[image]

Urls. py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='landing_page_new.html'), name='home'),           
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^login/', home, name='home'),
    url(r'^v1/', include(xyz_urls)),
]
```

xyzurls

```
from django.conf.urls import url,include
from django.contrib.auth.urls import urlpatterns
from ironman.views import *


urlpatterns = [
               url(r'^login/$', login),
               url(r'^signup/$', signup),

               ]
```

Comment: You'll need to give some information about what you're posting from postman.

Comment: Okay thanks for pointing out , let me post the request

Comment: Post the url.py code for this.

Comment: I have added url.py too , have a look

Comment: Why are you sending this as application/json?

Comment: not intentionally , I guess postman added it

Comment: removed Application/json still same error , Do't know whats happening

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the issue here is with PostMan.

You are actually making a get request. Remove both email and password by clicking on "x"

Next, go to Body --> formData --> Enter your params here

This will work.

Just a note, a POST request won't have parameters in the Url ever.

Comment: email = request.POST['email'] throws multidicterror

Comment: try email = request.POST.get('email') only, but did you have the dollar sign in the url.py file?

Comment: I tried still I am getting None , I never faced this issues I do not know what happening

Comment: no it is not issue with postman , I am not able to access through my mobile phone , it is giving same error , but If I am changing this to GET , it starts working , I am missing somthing thats for sure

Comment: You cannot create a POST request from your phone. I changed the answer, follow those steps.

Comment: from I am calling this api which is POST

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110005/discussion-between-kakshil-shah-and-naga).